# Database driver not found in parameters.yml in Symfony 2

Tags: database, symfony

i am newbie at Symfony , i just created a new Symfony 2.8 project using this command

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ecommerce "2.8.*"
```

the project is successfully created but since i have to work with pdo_mysql 
in the configuration file parameters.yml  i didn't find the " database_driver: pdo_mysql "
the database driver is not mentioned at all ! should i just add it manually in parameters.yml or how can i automatically generate it ?

Notice : PDO_Mysql is already installed and my PHP version is 5.6.31

this my parameters.yml file :

parameters.yml :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Comment: It is really just one of those quirks.  You will find it in app/config/config.yml.  I guess the assumption is that only one type of database will be used in most cases and keeping the type a secret is not a priority.  Feel free to add one if you want. https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database

Comment: does manually  adding databes_driver:pdo_mysql fixes it ?

Comment: Nope.  You will also need to tweak the doctrine section of your config.yml file.  Strange that you are learning 2.8 unless you have legacy apps to support.